# Limit scrolling to the y-position of a div [jQuery, javascript, HTML]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm currently working on a personal website where I have a lot of expandable items on my page. When an item is expanded I want to set the page scroll limit to the height of the expanded item, I don't want the user to scroll above or below the expanded item. I already tried *scroll(0, yPosition)* if the current scroll position is above or below the item, but that gives a very stuttering result... Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all the previous content of your page, when an item is expanded, and when it is supressed, set the content visible again.

Comment: I will try to explain how my website works. You'll see a list of items. When you click one, a _infobox_ containing additional information (text, tags, images, etc.) about the item will be shown **on top of the other items**. So when you scroll with a visible _infobox_, you will scroll the _infobox_ as well as the other items. This should only be possible when the _infobox_ is in the visible part of my website (window), otherwise no scrolling should be possible...

Comment: I drew back the earlier comment, it wasn't exactly what you want. But, set `style="overflow-y: scroll;"` for all infoboxes, and disable actual page scrolling with `document.body.scroll='no'`. To enable scrolling again, use `document.body.scroll='auto'` (or `'yes'`).